# How to generate a nested array of objects from an array of objects in nested set model?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that can convert a [nested set model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) array of objects to a normal nested array of objects within array of objects.

Currently, I'm not satisfied with my temporary solution that is limited to a depth of 2. Basically it is server-side controller using some Knex:

```
const getCategories = (res, db) => {
  db.raw(`
    SELECT child.id, child.name, child.path
    FROM product_category parent
    JOIN product_category child
    ON child.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
    WHERE parent.id = 1
      AND
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM product_category node
          WHERE child.lower BETWEEN node.lower AND node.upper
            AND node.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
        ) = 2 
    ORDER BY child.id
  `)
  .then(categories => {
    if (categories.rows.length) {
      const categoryPromises = categories.rows.map(category => {
        return db.raw(`
          SELECT child.id, child.name, child.path
          FROM product_category parent
          JOIN product_category child
          ON child.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
          WHERE parent.id = ${category.id}
          AND
            (
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM product_category node
              WHERE child.lower BETWEEN node.lower AND node.upper
                AND node.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
            ) = 2 
        `)
        .then(subcategories => {
          return { ...category, subcategories: subcategories.rows }
        })
      })

      return Promise.all(categoryPromises)
      .then(products => {
        res.json(products)
      })
    } else {
      res.status(400).json("No categories")
    }
  })
}
```

The schema is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a20af

Nested set model is a way of handling hierarchical data that encloses the children node into boundaries (commonly called `lft` and `rgt`). So if the `lft` and `rgt` values of `node1` are between the `lft` and `rgt` value of `node2`, it means that `node1` is a children of `node2` (I hope that cleared things up).

For example, I have the following array:

```
const categories = [
  {
      id: 1,
      name: "Products",
      lft: 1,
      rgt: 22
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      name: "Boats",
      lft: 2,
      rgt: 15
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      name: "Rescue Boats",
      lft: 3,
      rgt: 4
  },
  {
      id: 4,
      name: "Dive Boats",
      lft: 5,
      rgt: 6
  },
  {
      id: 5,
      name: "Tamarans",
      lft: 7,
      rgt: 8
  },
  {
      id: 6,
      name: "Dragon Boats",
      lft: 9,
      rgt: 10
  },
  {
      id: 7,
      name: "Kayaks",
      lft: 11,
      rgt: 12
  },
  {
      id: 8,
      name: "Speedboats",
      lft: 13,
      rgt: 14
  },
  {
      id: 9,
      name: "Other Products",
      lft: 16,
      rgt: 21
  },
  {
      id: 10,
      name: "Slides",
      lft: 17,
      rgt: 18
  },
  {
      id: 11,
      name: "Buoys",
      lft: 19,
      rgt: 20
  }
]
```

I want it to have an output something like this (or an array if there are multiple root nodes):

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Products",
  subcategories: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Boats",
      subcategories: [
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Rescue Boats"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Dive Boats"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Tamarans"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Dragon Boats"
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          name: "Kayaks"
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          name: "Speedboats"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "Other Products",
      subcategories: [
        {
          id: 10,
          name: "Slides"
        },
        {
          id: 11,
          name: "Buoys",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @TylerRoper Check the hyperlink in nested set model above: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @TylerRoper That array actually was straight from the database, I just didn't mention.

Comment: Sorry,  I just meant to say that I was referring to that nested set model. Basically, whatever is between the left and right boundaries is a child of that node.

Comment: @TylerRoper oh, I think I get it. It's a bit confusing but `lft` and `rgt` don't refer directly to *ids* - these are actually *bounds*. So `products` holds stuff that's between `1` and `22`. I do agree that a quick explanation here would definitely aid in answering the question.

Comment: Ah! You've both resolved my confusion. Thank you. OP, you may want to consider adding that simple explanation to your question, rather than relying solely on the article :)

Comment: Oh, and more importantly, but you should include an attempt to do this on your own. Right now you have no code in your question.

Comment: is categories elements are in right order with id ? and lft/rgt child are still inside the  lft/rgt parent ?

Comment: @MrJ Can you clarify more?

Comment: @TylerRoper My solution is a bit different from the question as it includes multiple SQL queries and promises that basically gets the first level depth node and then the children of that. I wanted to convert my example array above into the desired with JavaScript and handle dynamic depth.

Comment: is `categories[n].id < categories[n-1].id` and  `categories[n].lft < categories[n-1].lft` and `categories[n].lft < categories[n].rgt` allway true ?

Comment: Ah yes, the id's are unique but can have any order as long as the `lft` and `rgt` values are inside the parent. So if you want to sort it for example but the id's are scrambled, you can sort by the `lft` value.

Comment: @jp06 I understand that, however you're asking someone to write a JavaScript solution without having provided an attempt of your own. Your question doesn't include any sort of attempt to achieve your desired goal. It's more or less "someone write this JavaScript for me".

Comment: Fair enough, but I actually had attempts for THAT similar array in the example in React but really trashy and not even remotely working to be put here otherwise I would not have asked for help here. Instead I'll just put the server side code I use in Express with Knex. But it really is different type of solution.

Comment: I wrote the solution to your problem, but @TylerRoper is right. You should post even a trashy solution so we can show you the leaks in your approach to the problem.

Comment: Correct. When I said "an attempt", I meant "an attempt *to answer your own question*". Your question is "I wrote a solution, but want something totally different. Can someone write that for me?". It **should** be "I wrote this solution, but want something totally different. **I've attempted to write the new solution myself <insert new JavaScript here>**, but it isn't mapping properly. Can someone help me?". I realize this is moot at this point, but it's worth noting moving forward. If you write a question to which the answer will 100% brand new code, then you should rethink the question.

Comment: Not really my intention to sound like that. I actually might not have put some thought into constructing my question. I will keep that in mind, thank you. And first time actually seeing that kind of "recursive solution" in my few months of coding.

Comment: @jp06 It's no worry, I'm not trying to get on your case or berate you - it wasn't an egregious question or anything of that sort. However it's good to note moving forward. Good luck as you continue your coding journey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this recursive solution. Hope it can help. If you have any doubt please ask me.
I just check if an element is inside right and left property of another one. In this case I add it into his fathers (and each anchestor). I repeat the same operation until there are no more "fathers".

```js
const categories = [
  {
      id: 1,
      name: "Products",
      lft: 1,
      rgt: 22
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      name: "Boats",
      lft: 2,
      rgt: 15
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      name: "Rescue Boats",
      lft: 3,
      rgt: 4
  },
  {
      id: 4,
      name: "Dive Boats",
      lft: 5,
      rgt: 6
  },
  {
      id: 5,
      name: "Tamarans",
      lft: 7,
      rgt: 8
  },
  {
      id: 6,
      name: "Dragon Boats",
      lft: 9,
      rgt: 10
  },
  {
      id: 7,
      name: "Kayaks",
      lft: 11,
      rgt: 12
  },
  {
      id: 8,
      name: "Speedboats",
      lft: 13,
      rgt: 14
  },
  {
      id: 9,
      name: "Other Products",
      lft: 16,
      rgt: 21
  },
  {
      id: 10,
      name: "Slides",
      lft: 17,
      rgt: 18
  },
  {
      id: 11,
      name: "Buoys",
      lft: 19,
      rgt: 20
  }
]

function create_tree(array){
  if(array.every(x => array.every(y => !(y.lft > x.lft && y.rgt < x.rgt))))
    return array.map(x => {return{id:x.id, name:x.name, subcategories: x.subcategories}});
  else
  return create_tree(array.map(x => {return {
    id: x.id,
    name: x.name,
    lft: x.lft,
    rgt: x.rgt,
    subcategories: array.filter(y => y.lft > x.lft && y.rgt < x.rgt).map(t => {return (t.subcategories) ? {id: t.id, name: t.name, subcategories: t.subcategories} : {id: t.id, name: t.name}})
  }}).filter(t => t.subcategories && t.subcategories.length > 0));
}

console.log(create_tree(categories));
```